# Unable to build distribution file in Python Errno 2 No such file or directory

Tags: python

I am trying to build a distribution file in Python 3.4.3 (Windows)

I currently have two .py files in the folder 'nester'. The first is 'nester652399.py' which is as follows:

"""This is a module providing a function print_lol to print unknown levels of lists"""

```
def print_lol (the_list):
    """Check if each item in the list is a list"""

    for each_item in the_list:
        if isinstance(each_item, list):
            print_lol (each_item)
        else:
            print (each_item)
```

The second is 'setup.py' which is as follows:

from distutils.core import setup

```
setup(
    name = 'nester652399',
    version = '1.0.0',
    py_modules = ['nester'],
    author = 'AnUp',
    description = 'printer of nested lists',
    )
```

Entering the command `C:\Python34\python.exe setup.py sdist` in command prompt gives me the following error:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe: can't open file setup.py [Errno 2] no such file or directory
```

I'm new to Python and command prompt so I'd appreciate any light anyone can shed on this.

Comment: Do you run the command while in the same directory as your setup.py file?

Comment: That solved it, thanks.